# Best practice for implement a file-based cache

Tags: php, caching, io

I'm implementing a file-based cache system for my php application. When using, it can handle about 200,000 files stored in the same folder, making it difficult to manage: calculate the total size of the folder or list the files inside it can be near impossible to do in a reasonable time.

My question is: is good for performance save the files in separated folders? can this reduce the IO time?

Comment: It just makes listing slow, access time is not affected. Most file caching system's I've seen use a tree-based approach on the hash of the name of the file. This reduces considerably the number of files per directory. i.e file `bunny.txt` (sha1 `0d9228b316d694f2cb1a9add3fb71e29e55a060a`) will be stored at `0/d/9/0d9228b316d694f2cb1a9add3fb71e29e55a060a`. Tree depth can be adjusted on your needs.

Comment: We've moved beyond file caches at [Army.mil](http://www.army.mil) but if you check out the JS and CSS files on any page you can see how we composite them in much the same way. Looks a lot like what @Soohjun mentioned.

Comment: The most important thing for me is the access time, most of the times the operation is just seek and read the file

Comment: @JavierMarín It won't speed up access time, but it can make dealing with the cache itself easier. 200k files in one folder would be a problem if you ever wanted to work with it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

On a modern file system  (say ext3, ntfs) 200K files in a directory won't be slow if you are opening a single file. Listing will be slower ofcourse, but distributing your files over many directories won't help you there.